# Why Entity Framework create reference automatically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
using (db = new InsuranceEntities())
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            var result = db.CustomerQuotations.Where(m => m.IsActive == true)
                        .Include(m => m.CustomerDetails)
                        .Include(m => m.User.Role)
                        .Include(m => m.DocumentDetails);
            return result;
        }
```

If i am including User property. then User property also contain the list of CustomerQuotation so how i can avoid this in entity framework.

Comment: Because you're loading a `CustomerQuatation` via `db.CustomerQuotation.Where()` so the User will have a list with at least one `CustomerQuotation`, depending on the number of `CustomerQuotations` with the same user that are active.  You can't load one, include the other and expect the other not to reference the first.

Comment: can i avoid this?

Comment: Do you ever need this list?

Comment: No, you can't avoid this.

Comment: yes, i have problem while deserializing the result through web API. Even i m using   config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All  web api create reference but when i deserialize it some list item value are coming null

Comment: https://file.town/download/3gwzz1j7y4m6crjx1wtb9ltob this is my json

Comment: you can download and see why the reference become null while deserialize

Comment: This is a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking how to get EF to not load references (Y), but you should actually be asking how to (de)serialize the data into JSON (X).

Comment: i saw two ways for solving this problem. so i thought, i have to stop it it from the origin.